# Bash script running in Neovim ignores "read" command

Tags: bash, neovim

Consider the following Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -rp "> " INPUT
echo "Your input is: $INPUT"
echo "Done"
```

When I open this file in regular Vim and I run `:!bash %`, I get the expected result:

> > test
>
> Your input is: test
>
> Done
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

However, in Neovim, running the same `:!bash %` command seems to ignore the `read` line:

> Your input is:
>
> Done
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

I'm running Vim on version `8.2.500`, and Neovim on version `v0.4.3`.

Executing the script from the command line works fine, so far I'm only having this issue when running it within Neovim.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this specific to `read` in Bash or does it happen for all tools that read stdin?

Comment: @thatotherguy Good point, similar result on a Python script, so it seems to affect stdin in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual entry for the `:!` command:

> The command runs in a non-interactive shell connected
>               to a pipe (not a terminal). Use |[:terminal](https://neovim.io/doc/user/various.html#:terminal)| to run an
>               interactive shell connected to a terminal.

When it runs `bash`, its standard input is connected to a pipe, not the terminal, so you can't use the terminal to respond to prompts.

So try

```
!te bash %s
```

Comment: This was pretty much it! `:te bash %` did the trick for me. Thanks! There are a couple more key inputs required than in my Vim workflow, so I ended up declaring this binding to have an equivalent behavior in Neovim with F5: `autocmd FileType sh map <F5> <Esc>:w<CR>:te bash %<CR>i`